# Error 10054 in socket programming

Tags: c, sockets

I'm writing a socket programming code in C and I'm running a client and a server on the same computer.here is the code for server

```
  int main()
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        cout << "WSAStartup failed!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "socket failed with error:" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;

        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in service;
    service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    service.sin_family = AF_INET;
    service.sin_port = htons(5059);

    if (bind(sock, (SOCKADDR *)&service, sizeof(service)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "bind failed with error:" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;

        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    if (listen(sock, 5) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "listen failed with error:" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;

        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Waiting for a PKCS11 client ..." << endl;

        SOCKET accsock = accept(sock, NULL, NULL);
        if (accsock == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            cout << "accept failed with error:" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;

            closesocket(sock);
            WSACleanup();
            return -1;
        }

        cout << "PKCS11 client connected ..." << endl;

        while (true)
        {
            int receive_size = 0;
            char test[20];
            receive_size = recv(accsock, test, 20, 0);
            if (receive_size == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                cout << endl << "ERROR : "<<WSAGetLastError() << " PKCS11 client disconnected." << endl;
                closesocket(accsock);
                break;
            }

            test[receive_size] = '\0';
            command = temp;
            printf("recieved value is : %s\n",test);
          }
            }
```

and here is the code for client

```
int main(){
    /*CK_SESSION_HANDLE hSession = NULL;
    CK_MECHANISM_PTR pMechanism = NULL;
    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hKey = NULL;
    C_EncryptInit(hSession, pMechanism, hKey);*/

    char temp[10];
    printf("initialising ... \n");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error = :%d", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    printf("initialised\n");
    //create a socket
    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");


    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(5059);

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected");


    _itoa(CK_ENCRYPT, temp, 16);
    command = temp;
    int counter = 0;
    char* test = "H";
    while (counter != strlen(test)) {
    counter += send(s, test, strlen(test), 0);
    cout << counter << endl;
}   


    //while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I try to send more than one byte from client to server I get 10054 Error unless I uncomment the while(1) line which in that case I recieve the massage properly in the server.does anyone have any Idea what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Have you considered looking up Winsock error 10054?

Comment: Note that, if your little buffer is completely filled by the recv() call, 'test[receive_size] = '\0';' will be out-of-bounds:(

Answer (score 2):

Your client is sending data, which puts the data into the IP stack for sending. Then immediately afterwards it is terminating which means that the IP stack will cancel sending and un-gracefully close the socket.

You need to `shutdown` and `closesocket` the socket before terminating the client.

Comment: If you close the socket you don't need shutdown, except in the case where the socket has been inherited and you want it to definitely close now.